# Type 'ConnectedComponentClass<>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<DrawerItemsProps>

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

So i am using react-navigation in my react-native project with typescript and redux but when i an setting a the contentComponent prop for the drawerNavigator i am getting this error in typescript.

Type `'ConnectedComponentClass<SomeClass>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<DrawerItemsProps>' 
Type 'SomeClass' is missing the following properties from type 'DrawerItemsProps': navigation, items, getLabel, renderIcon, and 2 more.`.

Is there any workaround for the same.

Any help on the same would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Did you find my answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the type `DrawerItemsProps` has properties like `navigation, items, getLabel, renderIcon` and more and these are missing in your `SomeClass` interface.

So you can make all these properties which are missing as optional using '?' like below

```
interface DrawerItemsProps {
  // other properties
  navigation?: yourType,
  items?: yourType, 
  getLabel?: yourType,
  renderIcon?: yourType
}
```

Comment: nope i don't think thats the correct way of doing this, One needs to use one of type definitions provided by react-navigation in class props, this seems more like an ad-hoc solution.

Comment: @AmolGupta, Yes, I answered as you asked for a workaround

Comment: So react navigation exports a DrawerItemProps from react-navigation types I extended the class interface with the same and it work now. Thank you for all the help by the way.